# OpenXml Doc sdk 2.0 not producing DataSheet data in output

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using Open XML doc to create a spreadsheet and output it in memory stream and return it from server.  However the output does not include DataSheet/Worksheet contents. I tried various examples from different urls including VB.NET ones. All of them don't not include the contents from DataSheet. However, If I print the contents of the worksheet separately using Worksheet.OuterXml Property, its shown properly. Its not being printed as part of Workbook.OuterXml property. The sample code and output is given below.

```
private MemoryStream testSpreadsheetOutputAsStream()
    {
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(outStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            // create the workbook
            spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();     // create the worksheet
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet = new Worksheet();

            // create sheet data
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

            // create row
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.First().AppendChild(new Row());

            // create cell with data
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.First().First().AppendChild(
                  new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("101") });

            // save worksheet
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.Save();

            // create the worksheet to workbook relation
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().AppendChild(new Sheet()
            {
                Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "test"
            });

            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.OuterXml);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.OuterXml);
        }
        return outStream;

    }
```

The output from the output window is as below.

```
Worksheet output <x:worksheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:sheetData><x:row><x:c><x:v>101</x:v></x:c></x:row></x:sheetData></x:worksheet>

Workbook output

<x:workbook xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><x:sheets><x:sheet name="test" sheetId="1" r:id="R0ed99ee34c894367" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" /></x:sheets></x:workbook>
```

Comment: I suppose that it's correct when contents of a worksheet does not appear in the workbook xml. It's probably just because it contains only references to worksheets and contents of each of them is stored in a different part, so your file seems to be ok. Have you tried just to open it and see if it contains the data you enter in it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by calling spreadSheet.Close() after the call to spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save().

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the spreadsheet. A call to close recursively calls save on all the child-items.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close

Instead of trying to create a spreadsheet from scratch, consider using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or the take a look at the tiny spreadsheet library that I [wrote](https://github.com/jduv/OpenXmlDemo/tree/master/Slalom.OpenXml/Indexers/Spreadsheet). Specifically, pay attention to the [SheetDataIndexer](https://github.com/jduv/OpenXmlDemo/blob/master/Slalom.OpenXml/Indexers/Spreadsheet/SheetDataIndexer.cs) and the [SharedStringTableIndexer](https://github.com/jduv/OpenXmlDemo/blob/master/Slalom.OpenXml/Indexers/Spreadsheet/SharedStringTableIndexer.cs). I'm continually working on these examples as I do quite a bit of OpenXML manipulation in my own work.